# Last 24 Month data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to display 24 Months data (By months name), but as shown in the query, i have to put 24 columns for each Month, that will make my query to long.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT [STORE] = ET_LIBELLE,

CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,0),SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(GP_DATEPIECE) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
AND  month(GP_DATEPIECE) =  MONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
THEN ISNULL([SALES], 0) ELSE 0 END)) AS ' + DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MM,-1, GETDATE())) + ',

CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,0),SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(GP_DATEPIECE) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-2,GETDATE()))
AND  month(GP_DATEPIECE) =  MONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-2,GETDATE()))
THEN ISNULL([SALES], 0) ELSE 0 END)) AS ' + DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MM,-2, GETDATE())) + ',
.
.
.
FROM PIECE
GROUP BY ET_LIBELLE'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

RESULTS :

```
STORE   -   April   -   March   -   February   -   ..
--------------------------------------------------------
S1      -   5500    -   6530    -    4550      -   ..
S2      -   2400    -   8740    -    9650      -   ..
..
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any solution to optimise and make my query fast please ?

Comment: Please tag appropriate Database.

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: You are looking for last 24 month's data per store. Is it acceptable if you get data store and year wise with 12 column January to December?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following script will return data by 12 month (JAN to DEC) but 1 Row per year. If it is acceptable, you can use this query. You can also set the Month number (@HowManyMonth  = N) that for how many month you want to pick data.

```
DECLARE @HowManyMonth INT
SET @HowManyMonth = 24
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
SET @StartDate = CAST(DATEADD(DD,-(DAY(DATEADD(MM,-(@HowManyMonth-1),GETDATE()))-1),DATEADD(MM,-(@HowManyMonth-1),GETDATE())) AS DATE)

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Store,Sales,
    YEAR(GP_DATEPIECE) YR,
    CASE  MONTH(GP_DATEPIECE)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'JAN' WHEN 2 THEN 'FEB' WHEN 3 THEN 'MAR' WHEN 4 THEN 'APR' WHEN 5 THEN 'MAY' WHEN 6 THEN 'JUN'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'JUL'   WHEN 8 THEN 'AUG' WHEN 9 THEN 'SEP' WHEN 10 THEN 'OCT' WHEN 11 THEN 'NOV' WHEN 12 THEN 'DEC'
    END MONTH
    FROM PIECE
    WHERE GP_DATEPIECE >= @StartDate
)AS P
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Sales) 
    FOR MONTH IN ([JAN],[FEB],[MAR],[APR],[MAY],[JUN],[JUL],[AUG],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC])
) PVT
```

Comment: You mean December to January?

Comment: By previous months : Month -1, Month-2, Months-3, .. Month-12

Comment: This can be reordered as Dec-Nov-Oct---Jan. Not like you want :(

Comment: Anyway Thank's for your help